# jq is reordering keys within my JSON

Tags: json, key, jq

For some reason, and I have no idea why, when I test out formatting of the following lines on [jqplay](https://jqplay.org/#) it comes out looking different than when I run it on the command line.

[My original data looks as such:](http://pastebin.com/ew4AAkrY)

```
{"type":"user.list","users":[{"type":"user","id":"57db1b1b9jdjd84f99b977785ba","user_id":"janwjf3sqdditwn7c7","anonymous":false,"email":"test@diversifiedventures.net","phone":null,"name":"Joe Smith","pseudonym":null,"avatar":{"type":"avatar","image_url":null},"app_id":"b5vkddxvop","companies":{"type":"company.list","companies":[]},"location_data":{"type":"location_data","city_name":"Murfreesboro","continent_code":"NA","country_name":"United States","latitude":35.8896,"longitude":-86.3166,"postal_code":"37130","region_name":"Tennessee","timezone":"America/Chicago","country_code":"USA"},"last_request_at":1478624249,"last_seen_ip":"69.139.122.123","created_at":1473977115,"remote_created_at":1466313380,"signed_up_at":1466313380,"updated_at":1480970142,"session_count":1,"social_profiles":{"type":"social_profile.list","social_profiles":[]},"unsubscribed_from_emails":false,"user_agent_data":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko","tags":{"type":"tag.list","tags":[{"type":"tag","id":"587061","name":"Mixpanel Import - 2016-09-15 21:25:08 UTC"}]},"segments":{"type":"segment.list","segments":[{"type":"segment","id":"581a048c4ad88d6b458198d7"},{"type":"segment","id":"5845cd57c91b1fe3e440032b"},{"type":"segment","id":"5845cab9d951b43e7d33d2f7"}]},"custom_attributes":{"mixpanel_id":"1556710d919339-0beb72f2966b408-69581467-cff8c-1556710d91a54b","claimCount":"2","memberType":"claimant"}}],"scroll_param":"56386a4d-743b-470a-ae9f-848b991e0ccc"}
```

If you dump that into the [jq playground,](https://jqplay.org/#) it formats it exactly how it should be and how I want it, [which looks like this](http://pastebin.com/en8gSXbs):

```
{"type":"user","id":"57db1b1b9jdjd84f99b977785ba","user_id":"janwjf3sqdditwn7c7","anonymous":false,"email":"test@diversifiedventures.net","phone":null,"name":"Joe Smith","pseudonym":null,"avatar":{"type":"avatar","image_url":null},"app_id":"b5vkddxvop","companies":{"type":"company.list","companies":[]},"location_data":{"type":"location_data","city_name":"Murfreesboro","continent_code":"NA","country_name":"United States","latitude":35.8896,"longitude":-86.3166,"postal_code":"37130","region_name":"Tennessee","timezone":"America/Chicago","country_code":"USA"},"last_request_at":1478624249,"last_seen_ip":"69.139.122.123","created_at":1473977115,"remote_created_at":1466313380,"signed_up_at":1466313380,"updated_at":1480970142,"session_count":1,"social_profiles":{"type":"social_profile.list","social_profiles":[]},"unsubscribed_from_emails":false,"user_agent_data":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko","tags":{"type":"tag.list","tags":[{"type":"tag","id":"587061","name":"Mixpanel Import - 2016-09-15 21:25:08 UTC"}]},"segments":{"type":"segment.list","segments":[{"type":"segment","id":"581a048c4ad88d6b458198d7"},{"type":"segment","id":"5845cd57c91b1fe3e440032b"},{"type":"segment","id":"5845cab9d951b43e7d33d2f7"}]},"custom_attributes":{"mixpanel_id":"1556710d919339-0beb72f2966b408-69581467-cff8c-1556710d91a54b","claimCount":"2","memberType":"claimant"}}
```

That is precisely how I want the data to be restructured.

Go to the link for jqplay and see for yourselft, by simply typing this into the filter and clicking the compact output:

```
.users[]
```

But for some reason when I run this in the command line:

```
curl https://api.example.com/users/scroll -u 'dG9rOjg4YmUxMzr4XzJmNzZfNDkwY3934jU2X2mrM2MxZGEzYWI2MzoxOjA=': -H 'Accept:application/json'| jq -c '.users[]'
```

[It spits out a result that is totally not formmated how it is suppose to come out, despite using the exact same filter](http://pastebin.com/Bhqt9wQJ):

```
{"custom_attributes":{"memberType":"claimant","claimCount":"2","mixpanel_id":"1556710d919339-0beb72f2966b408-69581467-cff8c-1556710d91a54b"},"segments":{"segments":[{"id":"581a048c4ad88d6b458198d7","type":"segment"},{"id":"5845cd57c91b1fe3e440032b","type":"segment"},{"id":"5845cab9d951b43e7d33d2f7","type":"segment"}],"type":"segment.list"},"tags":{"tags":[{"name":"Mixpanel Import - 2016-09-15 21:25:08 UTC","id":"587061","type":"tag"}],"type":"tag.list"},"user_agent_data":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko","unsubscribed_from_emails":false,"social_profiles":{"social_profiles":[],"type":"social_profile.list"},"session_count":1,"updated_at":1480970142,"signed_up_at":1466313380,"pseudonym":null,"name":"Joe Smith","phone":null,"email":"test@diversifiedventures.net","anonymous":false,"user_id":"janwjf3sqdditwn7c7","id":"57db1b1b9jdjd84f99b977785ba","type":"user","avatar":{"image_url":null,"type":"avatar"},"app_id":"b5vkddxvop","companies":{"companies":[],"type":"company.list"},"location_data":{"country_code":"USA","timezone":"America/Chicago","type":"location_data","city_name":"Murfreesboro","continent_code":"NA","country_name":"United States","latitude":35.8896,"longitude":-86.3166,"postal_code":"37130","region_name":"Tennessee"},"last_request_at":1478624249,"last_seen_ip":"69.139.122.123","created_at":1473977115,"remote_created_at":1466313380}
```

Which as you can tell, is nothing like how it turns out in the jqplayground feature. To make matters even more confusing, someone else ran it and it formatted it correctly. On top of that, about a week ago, it worked fine for me.

I've also tried removing jq and reinstalling it with no success. I'm running it on Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-51-generic x86_64) if that somehow helps.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So what's "wrong" with it? How is it not formatted how you expected it?

Comment: @Jeff - It's an order-of-keys issue.

Comment: @wizkids121 - Please indicate the version of jq that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

jq 1.3 does not always respect the ordering of keys within JSON objects.  Assuming you are using jq 1.3 (or earlier), the solution would be to upgrade to a later version (1.4, 1.5, or the "master" version).